# How to set LinkTarget with Xamarin Studio 6 using Native References

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.ios-binding

I'm creating a xamarin.ios binding with Xamarin Studio 6. I've added the static library as Native References. But how can I set the LinkTarget (LinkTarget = LinkTarget.ArmV7 | LinkTarget.Simulator) via the Property window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed anymore since Xamarin.iOS will figure that out for you. Are you having any issues?

If you are having issues you can definitely use the old method by having the `FooLib.LinkWith.cs` and set yourself the `LinkWith` attribute there. Remove your lib from `Native References` folder and add your `FooLib.a` to your project root folder, it should still generate the `FooLib.LinkWith.cs` automagically.

Hope this helps!